# xsd to object with included xsd which contains same name elements

Tags: java, xjc

I have 4 xsd-s. The main xsd include an other one with contains same name elements and I have a catalog.xml. The company policy doesn't allow to change these xsd-s (don't ask why)

If I generate java class and compile only the one xsd, which contains the same name elements, I can make it with a binding.xml.
When I try to generate java class and compile from the main xsd, I cannot figure out, how I have to write the binding file.

Main xsd: `object.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:ac="http://aa.com/common"
        targetNamespace="http://aa.com/"
        xmlns:tns="http://aa.com/"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://aa.com/common"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="http://aa.com/include_good.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="http://aa.com/include_same_name_fields.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="ARequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="ac:GeneralRequest">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="body" type="tns:ARequestBodyType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="AResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="ac:GeneralResponse">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="body" type="tns:AResponseBodyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ARequestBodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tns:B" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AResponseBodyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tns:G" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

`aa.common.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://aa.com/common"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://aa.com/common">
    <xs:complexType name="GeneralRequest" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="GeneralResponse" abstract="true">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="body" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

`include_good.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="B">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="C">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="D"></xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="E"></xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="F"></xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

`include_same_name_fields.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="G">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DUPLICATE_NAME">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="H">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="DUPLICATE_NAME">
                                            <xs:complexType>
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element name="I" type="xs:string"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

`catalog.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<catalog xmlns='urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog'>

    <public publicId="http://aa.com/common" uri="common/aa.common.xsd"/>


    <system systemId="http://aa.com/include_same_name_fields.xsd" uri="include_same_name_fields.xsd"/>
    <system systemId="http://aa.com/include_good.xsd" uri="include_good.xsd"/>

</catalog>
```

This is the binding file for the `include_same_name_fields.xsd`, when you generate and complile only this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          if-exists="true" version="3.0">
    <bindings
            schemaLocation="../schemas/include_same_name_fields.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='H']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence
            /xs:element[@name='DUPLICATE_NAME']/xs:complexType">
            <class name="DUPLICATE_NAME_H"/>
        </bindings>
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.aa.test"/>
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
```

But I cannot figure out, how I need to change the binding file, if I would like to generate and compile the main xsd.

Here is the maven project on github: https://github.com/zsoltii/jakarta-xsd-to-object

I tried this binding file, but it doesn't found element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          if-exists="true" version="3.0">
    <bindings
            schemaLocation="../schemas/object.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='H']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence
            /xs:element[@name='DUPLICATE_NAME']/xs:complexType">
            <class name="DUPLICATE_NAME_H"/>
        </bindings>
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.aa"/>
        </schemaBindings>
    </bindings>

</bindings>
```

If you have any idea, how I change the binding file, go ahead.If I rename in the `include_same_name_fields.xsd` one of the duplicate name element, the maven project can generate and complile the java objects from xsd, so I think my setup is good, except the binding file.